# Implicit OAuth authentication is not redirecting

Tags: support, api, authentication, oauth2

I'm trying to build a simple iOS application , with login feature to stack overflow network.

I've read the documentation and choose to use `Implicit OAuth2.0`.
I've already registered an StackApps, so I've a `client_id` and so on..

For Authentication I use `UIWebView` with load request to my specific URL, something like:

```
URLWithString:@"https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=2975&scope=write_access,no_expiry&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success"]];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

But i'm unable to login with stack account !

When trying login with wrong parameters, shows me an error,
if parameters are correct, nothing happen !

i always remain on this page, even if login parameters were correct.

[image]

I expect redirect or something ...
What to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on iPhone emulator , i tested the same code on physical device iPhone and iPad with iOS7 , and worked as expected !